# Every click on addCart appear a new of the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to everytime i click on "addCart" appear a new of the same component ( another Bets>Example Number</Bets appears on the DOM).

```
const newBet: React.FC = () => {
  const [getAddCart, setGetAddCart] = useState([
    <BetsEmpty>Empty Cart</BetsEmpty>,
  ]);


  function addCart() {
    setGetAddCart([
        <Bets>
           Example Number
        </Bets>,
    ]);
  }

return(
        <AllBets>{getAddCart}</AllBets>
        <Button onClick={addCart}></Button>
)
}
```

Comment: Why would you store JSX components in the state?

Comment: What kind of multiple values, could you give an example ?

Comment: I want to add the same component but with different values, i will edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have stored `React Components` in your state which is not a suitable approach!
I recommend to store a list of objects instead and then check its length, it's empty`, show some text (e.g. your basket is empty), else map this list to a suitable component as follow:

```
const [state, setState]= useState([]);
```

then use it as follow:

```
state.length === 0? <h1>your basket is empty</h1>:
state.map(item=><h1>{item}</h1>) //if your item is String, if not u can provide more complicated component, its just an example
```

then your user can add another item as follow:

```
setState([...state, NEW ITEM]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just should add the stored objects in your `useState` and not the whole JSX component.

Then you can add values to it like

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

const addStuffToCart = (newItem) => setCart([...cart, newItem])
```

and map your cart to render all items in the list

```js
if (cart.length === 0) return <EmptyCart />
return cart.map(item => <ItemObject item={item} />)
```